# React - FIlter some object from array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, array-filter

I want to filter some object from array, but currently i only know remove single object, here's my current code looks like

```
const deleteChatList = (dispatch) => async (id) => {
    dispatch({type: 'delete', payload: id}) // need to change id to list of id or list of object
}
```

...

```
const chatListReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'fetch':
            return {...state, chatList: action.payload}
        case 'delete':
            return state.filter((chatList) => chatList.id !== action.payload)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: what is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who looking for an answer, this is works

```
case 'delete':
            return {...state, chatList: state.chatList.filter((chat) => !action.payload.includes(chat))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for membership check. Objects might also work.

```js
const deleteChatList = (dispatch) => async (chatListDeleted) => {
    dispatch({type: 'delete', payload: [id1, id2, id3]}) 
}
...

const chatListReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'fetch':
            return {...state, chatList: action.payload}
        case 'delete':
            const idSet = new Set(action.ids)
            return state.filter((chatList) => idSet.has(chartList.id))
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```